# Comparison of objects in django

Tags: python, django

Models

```
class Weapon_Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Gun(models.Model):
    weapon_type = models.ForeignKey(Weapon_Class, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    magazine_size = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    damage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    fire_rate = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    description = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views

```
class Weapon_class_view(ListView):
    model = Weapon_Class
    template_name = 'weapon_class.html'
    # print(Weapon_Class.objects.all()[1].headline)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items'] = Weapon_Class.objects.all().count()
        context['weapons'] = list(Weapon_Class.objects.all())
        context['arm'] = (Gun.objects.all())
   
        return context
```

Template

```
{% for weapon in weapons %}
    <div class = "wepbox" >
        <a href="#"><div class = "boxy">{{ weapon.title }}</div></a>
    </div>
    {% for g in arm %}
        {% if g.weapon_type == weapon.title %}
            <h1 style="color: yellowgreen;">{{g.name}}</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It displays nothing on the browser but it should display the name of different guns like type 25 which is the assault rifle or MW11 which is the pistol

Comment: You're trying to loop `arm` from within the `weapons` loop. From within that loop arm isn't a contextual object. Also why are you specifying weapons as context when you can access it via `guns` foreign key?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't know how to access it via a foreign key. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing it. Convert it into a string. Use slugify

```
    {% for g in arm %}
        {% if g.weapon_type|slugify == weapon.title|slugify %}
            <a href="#"><div class="subsubbox">{{ g.name }}</div></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```